# Produce full equation with answer in C#

Tags: c#

Here is my problem

I would like to have a label produce both the formula AND the answer.

Here is what I have...please help.

```
   int score1 
   int score2

   double addition

   score1 = int.Parse(txbNumber1.Text);
   score2 = int.Parse(txbNumber2.Text);

   addition = score1 + score2;

   lblAdditionResults.Text = addition.ToString();
```

Comment: Are you asking a question (Or) saying something else? confused?

Comment: can you write example of your desired output ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C# 6 answer using template strings:

```
lblAdditionResults.Text = $"{addition} = {score1} + {score2}";
```

See [the official guide about interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160(v=vs.140).aspx).

Comment: +1 for being ahead of the times, would suggest also posting a solution that works for non beta testers too.

Comment: @toby I assumed other people would add an answer not using the new syntax - I merely wanted to promise it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
lblAdditionResults.Text = string.Format("{0} + {1} = {2}",score1,score2,addition)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lblAdditionResults.Text = String.Format("{0} + {1} = {2}", score1, score2, addition);
```